# How to load external file in child window of electron main window in electronjs

Tags: electron, next.js

I have created an application with electron and next.from main window, creating child window. I want to load file to child window but it is throwing file not found error.

loading file is in: renderer/components/overlay/overlay.html

```
import {app,BrowserWindow,remote,globalShortcut} from 'electron';
import OverlayWindow from '../components/overlay/overlay';

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const os=require('os');

export const createOverlayWindow=()=>{
    const overlayWindow = new remote.BrowserWindow({
        width:300,
        height:100,
        frame:false,
        webPreferences: {
            transparent: true,
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    // overlayWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    // overlayWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/renderer/components/overlay/overlay.html`)    
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'overlay.js'));
    const urlFormat=url.format({
         pathname:  path.join(__dirname,"renderer/components/overlay/overlay.html" ),
         protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true
    })
    console.log(urlFormat);
    overlayWindow.loadURL(urlFormat);
    const shortcut = remote.globalShortcut.register('Alt+Space', () => {
        console.log('shortcut registered');
        overlayWindow.show();
      });
    overlayWindow.webContents.setFrameRate(30)
}
```

[image]

Comment: let me know about his code result
`console.log(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'overlay.js'));`

Comment: consoles \overlay.html

Comment: @tpikachu urlFormat returns file:///\renderer\component\overlay\overlay.js

Comment: Can you attach the current project file structure image?

Comment: added file structure image

Comment: Is this background.js?

Comment: I wanted to create overlay window .so I'm following this method

Comment: yes its main entry file for electron where mainwindow is created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207733/discussion-between-tpikachu-and-krazy).

Comment: @tpikachu whether I'm doing it wrong

Comment: You need to know where the files are stored after being packaged with webpack.Because the packaged file path is different from your current path